# Is it possible to limit the file size or count when creating external table in azure data warehouse?

Tags: azure, data-warehouse

While creating external tables in azure data warehouse,
files are generated in the location we set.
Currently we noticed that the file size and count are decided by the scale level of data warehouse.
I'm curious is it possible to set those values like, only generate not more than 100 files,
or each file should not greater than 5 GB.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So far it is not possible to set up those. it's all automatically decided by Azure DW.